# Sublime Text 2 CSS recommended comment style

Tags: comments, sublimetext2

When you hit Ctrl + R (Cmd + R) in a commented CSS file, then the structure is somewhat ordered, but I am unable to find information on how the logic is applied.

For example
    /** 
    Hello
    */
is displayed as `** Hello **` as opposed to regular `CSS: body`

Does sublime apply any logic on generating this list and is it possible to create multi-level "table of contents" using comments on hitting Ctrl + R?

Comment: What do you mean by "logic"? From a few minutes of messing around, it seems to me that in the Goto Anything symbol search (what you're doing with `Ctrl+R`), regular CSS rules and docstring-like comments (`/** Comment */`) are listed in the order that they appear within the file; CSS rules are prefixed by `CSS:` and comments are surrounded by `** ... **`. Single-asterisk comments are ignored. You couldn't make a hierarchy out of the list, but you could assign labels to certain sections of the stylesheet with `/** Label */`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime doesn't support the multi-level commenting by default. Just use `/**` instead of `/*` for the command to show up in the Ctrl+R dialog.